# if $n$ is a positive int and $n$ is a square of int then $n \neq 2 \bmod 3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I am trying to prove exactly what the title says:

if $n$ is a positive int and $n$ is a square of int then $n \neq 2 \bmod 3$

This is my attempt:

I split it into two cases:

Case 1: $n$ is even

$n=(2k)^2$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z$

$(2k)^2$ = $4(k^2) = 1 \bmod 3 \neq 2 \bmod 3$

Case 2: $n$ is odd

$n=(2k+1)^2$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z$

and this is where I got stuck (well I'm not even sure if this is the right way to approach this proof):

$n=4k^2 + 4k + 1 = 4(k^2+k)+1 = 2 \bmod 3$??

Where did I go wrong.

Comment: What is $\wedge n$?

Comment: I wrote $\wedge$ instead of and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing casework on $n$, you should do it on $k$ where $n=k^2$. $k$ is either $0,1$ or $2\bmod3$, and for each case you can check that $n\not\equiv2\bmod3$, proving the statement.

Comment: could you elaborate on what you mean by 'k is either 0,1,2 or mod 3'

Comment: so let's say case1 is when $k$ is $0$ $mod$ $3$, where do you go from there?

Comment: I still don't understand the difference between $k=0,1,2 mod 3$. If $k$ is $0$ mod $3$, then doesn't that just apply for all 0,1,2?

Comment: I think I got it, for case 1 remainder is $k=0mod3$ which means $k=3s$ for some int s and $n$ satisfies since $n=9s^2$ which is still mod3. for case 2: $k=3s+1$ and $n = 9s^2 +6s+1$ = $3(s^2 +3s)+1$ which still satisfies $n=1mod3$ but for case 3: $k=3s+2$ and $n=9s^2+12s+4$ which is $n=3(3s^2+4s)+4$ which is 1mod3?

Comment: @ph-quiett Yeah, like that.

Comment: You are right @ph-quiett

Comment: $\neq 2mod3$ $\therefore$ the proof is complete?

Comment: @ph-quiett Yes.

Comment: thanks guys appreciate it